# How can i convert an SQL query to laravel elequent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the following sql query working fine in a php app, but i can't figure it out in laravel elequent

The sql is basically about retrieving the number of views per day over the course of 30 days

```
SELECT
DATE('created_at') AS 'day',
COUNT(*) AS 'titles'
FROM `views`
where view_type ='App\\Title'
GROUP BY DATE('created_at')
order by DATE('created_at') desc
limit 30
```

Any help

Edit 1:
DB structure

```
`id` bigint(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `view_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `view_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Do you have a sample database table and inserts we can play around with so we can try running our attempts locally before answering?

Comment: What have you tried? add your code.

Comment: @KevinY, i added the table structure

Comment: day returns NULL for me when I run your query on some valid dummy data. Are you sure your query works correctly before converting it over?

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table("views")
->select("date ('created_at') as `day`", "count (*) as `titles`")
->where("view_type", "=", 'App\\Title')
->limit(30)
->orderBy("created_at","desc")
->groupBy("created_at")
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use from `DB::raw` in laravel .

```
$results = DB::select(
DB::raw("SELECT
DATE('created_at') AS 'day',
COUNT(*) AS 'titles'
FROM 'views'
where view_type ='App\\Title'
GROUP BY DATE('created_at')
order by DATE('created_at') desc
limit 30");
```